# What does the 'where' keyword mean in C?

Tags: c, syntax

I stumbled across this C code today. Can anyone tell me what the 'where' keyword means:

```
*y = sy + exit->y + (where * (entry->y + esy - exit->y));
```

Edit:

Ah.. my bad. It is just a variable name. VC++ highlighted it as though it was a keyword though.

Comment: Ignore the SO syntax highlighting - it's just highlighting common keywords (SQL for example)

Comment: We can probably close this now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a variable name...

(The `where` is highlighted as blue here only because C# supports `where` as a keyword in LINQ.)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a list of C's keywords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Reserved_keywords). There is no `where` keyword in C, it's just a variable (or perhaps a macro).